# Facebook Mypersonality dataset

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, social-media, web-crawling

I want to have access to a database for Facebook Photos dictionary that contains 17,2mn records (photo_id,owner_id, created_time).

At this time, the owner of the dataset has decided to stop sharing the data further and I do assume that the external researcher which already have a legal copy before this restriction can continue their work based on that we did not get any note saying against this. Therefore, I decided to find a way to map this missing profile pictures dataset from the available datasets using Facebook graph API.

So far, I have copies for two datasets. One contains Facebook users self-reported personality test (BIG5 Personality Scores.zip) and the other one contains a users race prediction-based profile picture (Race labels.zip). The authors say that all of the tables contain an anonymized user id (32 characters) that can be used to match users between tables.

So, if the same id is being found in the two databases, can I assume that the two separated records are for the same user? at this point, can I then use this mapped id to crawl the original facebook profile picture?

Comment: :- Is it possible to share the link of the data (BIG5 Personality Scores.zip and Race lables.zip) that you have ?

Comment: @Sid29 https://web.archive.org/web/20180428085315/http://mypersonality.org/wiki/doku.php?id=download_databases

Comment: Have you solved the problem?
I also encountered the same problem